# Reading a file in java by line

Tags: java, file, line

I am trying to read a txt file in java. I have to separate each line of the code and put each individual line into a new array object comprised of each number, which are separated by commas. The file is long but to summarize it looks like this.

```
1,2,12343,12422,12342,12322,12421
2,3,12322,42444,24344,24553,34535
```

How would I write the code to add each line into an array with that lines numbers as its content?

Answer (score 1):

Using nio Path, Files and streams:

```java
Path path = Path.of(filename);
List<int[]> arrays = Files.lines(path)
    .map(line -> line.split(","))
    .map(split -> Stream.of(split).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it in a loop within a try and catch?

Comment: Don't forget to close the `Stream` returned by `Files#lines(Path)`.